# Running another python script with os.system

Tags: python, os.system

I have old python. So can't use subprocess.
I have two python scripts. One primary.py and another secondary.py.
While running primary.py I need to run secondary.py.

Format to run secondary.py is 'python secondary.py Argument'

`os.system('python secondary.py Argument')...is giving error saying that can't open file 'Argument': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: You *can* use the [subprocess backport](https://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/).

Comment: You mention in a comment below that you are using python 2.6.  Subprocess is available for that version of python.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you described, this error can come up for three reasons:

- `python` isn't on your `PATH`, or
- `secondary.py` isn't in your current working directory.
- `Argument` isn't in your current working directory.

From your edited question, it sounds like it's the last of the three, meaning the problem likely has nothing to do with `system` at all… but let's see how to solve all three anyway.

First, you want a path to the same `python` that's running `primary.py`, which is what [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is for.

And then you want a path to `secondary.py`. Unfortunately, for this one, there is no way (in Python 2.3) that's guaranteed to work… but on many POSIX systems, in many situations, [`sys.argv\[0\]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) will be an absolute path to `primary.py`, so you can just use `dirname` and `join` out of [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to convert that into an absolute path to `secondary.py`.

And then, assuming `Argument` is in the script directory, do the same thing for that:

```
my_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
os.system('%s %s %s' % (sys.executable, 
                        os.path.join(my_dir, 'secondary.py'),
                        os.path.join(my_dir, 'Argument')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Which python version do you have?
Could you show contents of your secondary.py ?
For newer version it seems to work correctly:

```
ddzialak@ubuntu:$ cat f.py 
import os
os.system("python s.py Arg")

ddzialak@ubuntu:$ cat s.py

print "OK!!!"
ddzialak@ubuntu:$ python f.py
OK!!!
ddzialak@ubuntu:$
```

Comment: Just because it works in one scenario doesn't mean it works in every possible scenario. Your code will not work if, e.g., `python` isn't on the PATH, and you do `/opt/python23/bin/python f.py` at the shell.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Both files primary.py and secondary.py are in the same directory.....I have python 2.6.2......I need to run secondary.py Argument at the shell....secondary.py basically searches for files with name "Argument" in the current directory and prints them....It works fin when I run secondary.py independently....only when I try to do it through primary.py that I am getting the error.....Thanks a lot again

Comment: Yes, I know very well that example is not a proof. Anyway for me it's very unexpected to have message like: `can't open file 'Argument'` - if there would be some problem with PATH then message will say that `python` or `secondary.py` could not be opened.

Comment: If you have python 2.6.2 then `subprocess` should be available (since 2.4)